# Deploy new instances with the same terraform file without damaging the old one's

Tags: linux, kvm, terraform

I am using a terraform file to deploy 2 VM instances in parallel (on KVM).

now I need to deploy another 2 VM instances with the same terraform file.

how can I do this without damaging the old instances?

when running again the "terraform apply" command, it recreated the old machines...

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: wouldn't you just put "I need 4 instances in total" in the file and let that run?